# Instances of alternative notation being used for the trigonometric functions?

Tags: mathematics, notation

Consider the three "main" trigonometric functions, sine cosine and tangent; whose notations are sin(x); cos(x); tan(x).

Are there instances of alternative notations being used for these particular functions?
The only one I could find so far was the [use of "tang" by Leonard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry) for even when referencing trigonometry from Indian Babylonian, Egyptian or Chinese antic cultures, wikipedia uses the standard notation.

Comment: In Spanish, "sine" is "[seno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seno_(trigonometría))" and the notation for "sin(x)" is "sen(x)."

Comment: In Soviet Union they used $\mathrm{tg}, \mathrm{ctg}, \mathrm{csc}$ for $\tan, \cot,$ and  $\mathrm{cosec}$.

Comment: There was no true trigonometry in Babylonian and Egyptian culture. The Greeks (who invented trigonometry) had only one trigonometric function, the chord $\mathrm{chd}(x)=2\sin(x/2)$, but they did not use this notation; it was invented by 20 century historians to deal with the Greek science. The rest of trig functions are medieval inventions.

Comment: Partial overlap with this: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/what-is-the-etymology-behind-sine-cosine-tangent-etc

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko you got the use of csc and cosec backwards.  The only place I've seen cosec is in Russian math books.

Comment: Notation cosec exists also in French.

Comment: Have you also heard about versine, haversine, etc. functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine) ?

Comment: @Jean Marie Becker Yes but I wanted to specifically focus on the  "main three"

Comment: @downvoter an explanation and/or some advice would be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Notation in indian trigonometry

The Indian mathematician and astronomer [Aryabhata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryabhata) (476-550 CE) was the author of first [sine table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80ryabha%E1%B9%ADa%27s_sine_table) ever.
It was a  stanza composed of sanscrit [Alphanumerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80ryabha%E1%B9%ADa_numeration) and words, which contained relations between arcs and half-chords of a circle.

So in this way of writing, notation for sine would just be it's name.
The sanscrit word for half-chord is *ardha-jyā* what we would commonly see today as the sine.

[image: litteral meaning]

However, the word *jyā* ( ज्या in sanscrit ) came to mean *half-chord* when *ardha-jyā* was shortened :
[image: technical meaning]

So the notations would be:

```
   sine : ज्या (jyā)
   cosine : कोटिज्या (koti-jyā)
```

*jyā* passed into Arabic as *jība* and was corrupted into *jaib* which means "bosom" and translates to *sine* in Latin

### Feynman Notation

Apparently, during his younger years, The physicist Richard Feynman invented his own notation for the trig functions (which was never really used afterwards) :

[image: Feynman trig notation]

sources : 
    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274463/feynman-trig-notation-creating-custom-characters

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/feynmans-trig-notations.78087/