# Earliest drawings of the plots of trigonometric functions

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, notation, geometry, education

*[Even though this question may seem as a duplicate of this question about the [History of sine function](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/history-of-sine-function), I'd like to ask it again - with a more specific title and a more specific focus (on specific references) which hopefully will re-attract some users.]*

---

The sine of an angle is the ratio of the length of the opposite side to the length of the hypotenuse and this is the mental picture one must have in mind:

[image]

This or similar pictures can be found in many ancient texts on trigonometry.

But today, when hearing "sine" many people inevitably have in mind a mental picture like this:

[image]

and it's not so hard to understand how it arises from the first picture (by rotating the radius with constant speed and plotting the sine):

[image]

This was not always so: neither has there been this mental picture of the 
sine function nor have there been physical drawings.

My question is:

> What are the earliest (known) physical drawings of the plot of the sine or
>   another trigonometric function?

Are they Greek, Indian, Chinese or from the Middle Ages? A specific reference would be welcome.

---

This may not be the earliest reference, but it's a rather early one, as I suppose:

[image]

(Albrecht Dürer: [Underweysung der Messung, mit dem Zirckel und Richtscheyt, in Linien, Ebenen unnd gantzen corporen](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite%3ADuerer_Underweysung_der_Messung_021.jpg), 1525)

Comment: Very closely related, and possible a duplicate --- [History of sine function](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/history-of-sine-function)

Comment: Thanks to @DaveLRenfro:  I found an explicit reference in this [answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3415/6422): https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite%3ADuerer_Underweysung_der_Messung_021.jpg (which may not be the earliest known plot).

Comment: If Alexandre and Mauro’s answers could be moved (or repeated) here, perhaps we might best close the *other* question, which was only for sine and whose author apparently *never even returned* to read the answers. Boyer ([1947](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27953231)) mentions early graphs by Roberval (c.1635), Wallis (1670), Cotes ([1722](https://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1255804)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [History of sine function](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/history-of-sine-function)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Please see the "discussion" that already took place.

Comment: To close the other question the software wants an accepted answer here. @MauroALLEGRANZA ?

Comment: The picture is a little misleadind : the legend make it clear that Dürer thinks to a 2D projection of a 3D form, an helix (schneck=snail). Thus, yes, it coincides with a sinusoidal curve, but...

Comment: How crazy: the more complicated 3D curve was plotted before its 2D companion?